# overall bytes in Xcode Instruments reaches 1 GB is that ok?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, memory-management, instruments

Here is my question.

I tried to check my allocation part using Instruments in xcode. 
I am doing some image crop Application using **CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex** for processing the images. while doing the process it is taking to much memory and i **released** it in right manner.

[image: This image shows how memory is released]

In Instruments the **live bytes** is 1.56Mb , **#living** = 22,862 and **Overall bytes** reaches 1.11Gb after that also it will increase.

This application is not working in ipad1. i dont have ipad2 or 3 in hand to test the application.

In the image some peak points are there. At that point **Live Bytes** reaches 73MB. and it will be released.  will ipad 2 handle this peak ??

[image: Peak point reaches 73MB]

Can anyone tell this will cause any memory Problem in device.

How about the overall bytes. is there any limit for this?

Comment: [Instruments User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: share your code to me.

Comment: There is some logical error in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes since overall bytes is just the number of bytes that were EVER allocated.

The longer the app runs, the higher the no.

Comment: thabks for the answer. can you please tell me whether ipad 2 is capable of handing 73 MB of live bytes for small time period??

Comment: depends -- there is no CLEAR yes/no here. from the hardware sure. but under normal conditions: yes :)

Comment: so that i need to test the app in device. let me try it. anyway thanks for you help.