# Live Bytes of app reaches above 1 GB and simulator shows blank screen

Tags: ios, memory, malloc, instruments

I am working in a big project. There was no problem till last hour. Suddenly my app's live bytes keeps on increasing and it touches above 1 GB and I can't even identify where the problem is. I have searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758061/overall-bytes-in-xcode-instruments-reaches-1-gb-is-that-ok) but its for overall bytes not for live bytes.

I got the following error after five minutes:

```
xxxxxx(1456,0x252d1a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
```

Here is a screenshot of Instruments and you can see the live bytes reaches 1 GB.

[image]

I've tried the following steps

1. Reset the contents and settings of simulator
2. Delete Xcode full application files
3. Delete all derived files and clean trash fully
4. Re-install Xcode

To be more correct error found in this lines

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UserNameTxtFld setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:242.0f/255.0f green:245.0f/255.0f blue:245.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];

    [UserPasswordFld setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:242.0f/255.0f green:242.0f/255.0f blue:242.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];

    [LoginButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:60.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:113.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];

    //[ForgotButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    API=[[BMAPIClass alloc] init];
    API.delegate    =   self;

    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, UserNameTxtFld.frame.size.height)];

    UserNameTxtFld.leftView = paddingView;

    UserPasswordFld.leftView =paddingView;

    self.appDelegate   =   (BMAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //Set Splash screen

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 480)
        {
            // iPhone Classic
            NSLog(@"iphone 4");

            if(IS_RETINA)
            {
                NSLog(@"Yes retina Display");
                splashScreenImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_640x960.jpg"];
                [visiblePassword setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eye_640x960.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Not retina Display");
                splashScreenImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_320x480.jpg"];
                [visiblePassword setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eye_320x480.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
        if(result.height == 568)
        {
            // iPhone 5
            NSLog(@"iphone 5");
            splashScreenImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_640x1136.jpg"];
            [visiblePassword setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eye_640x1136.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }


}
```

Nothing's worked. Can any one could say what the problem is?

Comment: Did you use Instruments to see what objects are part of the live byte allocation and what code created them?

Comment: hope it is not with code bcz last few hours i never touched code i am sure i changed somethings in UI after that only this problem arises

Comment: Check if you accidentally left NSZombies enabled. Yesterday I was wondering why my app needs Gigabytes of RAM, turned out I left NSZombies on.

Comment: instruments getting full of hanged so i cant see which object creates the problem couldnt check further more

Comment: from the screenshot you've uploaded it seems that you are viewing just the allocations...check the leaks as well..If nothing shows up as a leak do try out this technique - http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: There is an issue in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen your code in this [Link](http://pastie.org/8605715#4,16,22)

As per your given code you have used same code multiple time.

```
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, UserNameTxtFld.frame.size.height)];

    UserNameTxtFld.leftView = paddingView;

    UserNameTxtFld.leftViewMode =UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    UserPasswordFld.leftView =paddingView; // this is wrong(can't use it again)
    UserPasswordFld.leftViewMode =UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

You can't use same padding view again. You have to alloc it again for `UserPasswordFld` field. Take another padding view and use it then it will work.

Comment: tnx a lot for guiding me

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you.